# Insert value from other Sheets at certain interval

Tags: excel, vba

So basically I wanted a simple program where I could update the value of 1 cell from other sheets at certain interval, let's say for every 20ms.
I am using Timer instead of For Loop because I wanted it to be at precise interval, not immediate.

```
Option Explicit
Public RunFlag As Boolean
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single

Sub StartTimer()
    TimerSeconds = 20 ' how often to "pop" the timer.
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)
   
Dim SetValue As Single
Dim i As Integer
   
        If i = 0 Then
            i = 1
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).value
            i = i + 1
        
        ElseIf i >= 1 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).value
            i = i + 1
        
        End If
 
End Sub

Sub btnInit()

StartTimer

End Sub
```

So when I click the button, the Timer should start and it should proc at 20ms interval, but it doesn't.
Must be something wrong with the TimerProc but I am not sure what to do about it.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to give a value to the variable `i`.

Comment: nope, doesn't work as well. It only reads the first value, same as before. I think if I define i at every proc, it will reset at the first defined value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `i` variable as public too, because it is resetting every single time your timer repeats the TimerProc

Here a working code, I added the initialization of `i` at the **StartTimer**, included a third conditional in **TimerProc** to exit the loop and set the `i` to 0 in the **EndTimer**:

```
Option Explicit
Public RunFlag As Boolean
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single
Public i As Long

Sub StartTimer()
    TimerSeconds = 500 ' how often to "pop" the timer.
    i = 1
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
    i = 0
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)
   
    Dim SetValue As Single

    If i = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
        i = i + 1
    
    ElseIf i >= 2 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
        i = i + 1

    ElseIf i = 0 Then
        EndTimer
    End If
 
End Sub

Sub btnInit()

    StartTimer

End Sub
```